# Can't install any eclipse UI themes on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install a new eclipse UI theme, as staring at a white UI all day makes my eyes hurt. Specifically, I'm trying to install the following: https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme

However, despite following all of the different installation options they list on that github ReadMe, I can't get it to work. No matter what I do, only the standard three themes show up, as displayed in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOcir.jpg

Exactly the same thing happened (i.e. nothing) when I tried to install another eclipse UI theme. So I'm guessing this is some sort of problem with my eclipse.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I'd really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: did you try dragging and dropping the plugin into your workbench?

Comment: You can also download the theme xml and install it in your preferences under eclipse.

Comment: AmitApollo: unfortunately dragging and dropping has no effect. Nothing happens!

Comment: I'm eager to try your xml suggestion. Where is the theme xml and how do I install it in eclipse? Do I import it?

Comment: Your work bench is where your console is towards the bottom.

Comment: You should be using Juno or Keplar or Luna version of Eclipse. The older versions don't let you drag and drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running an old version of eclipse, try updating to Juno at least (4.2.x)

For older version of eclipse you can look at this [plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme), but will only modify the editor, not the whole IDE

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded to Luna and now it works perfectly. Thank you both very much for your help, and sorry I was being so stupid! I'd updated eclipse within itself via its update, but I guess that doesn't install the latest version!